# How to Display a List of Users Who Have Made at Least 1 Post?

Tags: posts, count, post-status, users

What I would like to do is have a list of users who have contributed at least one post.

I need to show the following:

**[User photo] | [User Name] | [User post count]**

e.g.

**[photo] Joe Bloggs(8)**

I made a start and went down this route:

```
<?php
   $blogusers = get_users( 'orderby=post_count' );
      foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
      echo '<li>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</li>';
   }
?>
```

However, this seems to just return all users registered to the blog rather than those who have contributed so I'm certainly not doing it correctly.

I am new to wordpress and PHP so all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Want something styled? Try this http://wpsites.net/web-design/author-contributors-page-template/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the `who` parameter in [`get_users`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)

```
<?php
   $blogusers = get_users( 'orderby=post_count&who=authors' );
      foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
      echo '<li>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</li>';
   }
?>
```

**EDIT**

Seems I was to fast answering. The code in your question and in my answer is the start to what you want to achieve.

I don't have time to code now, off to watch rugby, but here is the complete code used in the twenty fourteen to display authors and their post count. Hope this helps

```
function twentyfourteen_list_authors() {
    $contributor_ids = get_users( array(
        'fields'  => 'ID',
        'orderby' => 'post_count',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'who'     => 'authors',
    ) );

    foreach ( $contributor_ids as $contributor_id ) :
        $post_count = count_user_posts( $contributor_id );

        // Move on if user has not published a post (yet).
        if ( ! $post_count ) {
            continue;
        }
    ?>

    <div class="contributor">
        <div class="contributor-info">
            <div class="contributor-avatar"><?php echo get_avatar( $contributor_id, 132 ); ?></div>
            <div class="contributor-summary">
                <h2 class="contributor-name"><?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $contributor_id ); ?></h2>
                <p class="contributor-bio">
                    <?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'description', $contributor_id ); ?>
                </p>
                <a class="button contributor-posts-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( $contributor_id ) ); ?>">
                    <?php printf( _n( '%d Article', '%d Articles', $post_count, 'twentyfourteen' ), $post_count ); ?>
                </a>
            </div><!-- .contributor-summary -->
        </div><!-- .contributor-info -->
    </div><!-- .contributor -->

    <?php
    endforeach;
}
```

Simply call it in your template files as

```
twentyfourteen_list_authors();
```

Comment: You could also add a status parameter http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters

Comment: IIRC that display users that have capability to post, not user that have effectively posted something.

Comment: I'm referring to if have published posts  if ( ! $post_count ) { continue;

Comment: Pieter, I think I can improve performance of your function, look at my answer ;)

Comment: [`count_many_users_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_many_users_posts) function should be used for efficiency, when counting for a set of multiple users.

Comment: @Rarst why not add that as an answer. You know how useful info go to waste in comments, no one really reads them :-)

Answer (score 6):

There is no default way in WordPress to do this task, as **Pieter Goosen** pointed out, exists the argument `who` for `get_users()` that returns users that *can* post, not the users that *have* posted.

However, you can use `'pre_user_query'` to add a `JOIN` SQL clause to only get users that have at least one post.

To be honest, when you query users ordering them by post count, the join is already created by WordPress, but using an `OUTER LEFT JOIN`, so even users with no posts are returned, so the only thing you need is to replace the `OUTER LEFT JOIN` to a `INNER JOIN`

```
function filter_users_have_posted( $user_query ) {
   $user_query->query_from = str_replace( 'LEFT OUTER', 'INNER', $user_query->query_from );
   remove_action( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
}

add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'filter_users_have_posted' );

$blogusers = get_users( 'orderby=post_count&order=desc' );
```

Comment: Must you burst my bubble, lol :-). Great answer, must say. Never thought in that direction to be honest. +1

Comment: Thats great information to know! Thanks for your help. Just tried your solution and that also gets me close to where I need to be. :)

Answer (score 4):

Since version `4.3.0`, you can now specify the parameter `has_published_posts` to the `get_users();` function call.

> Pass an `array` of post types to filter results to users who have
>   published posts in those post types. `true` is an alias for all public
>   post types.

---

**Example**

```
if ( $users = get_users( array(
    'orderby'             => 'nicename',
    'order'               => 'ASC',
    'has_published_posts' => array( 'post' ),
    'blog_id'             => absint( get_current_blog_id() )
) ) ) {
    print_r( $users );
}
```

---

**Resources**

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/